# How can I track highlight duplicates in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a project at work where my task is to mark out duplicates on the spread sheet. So basically I have a 50,000 line spread sheet filled with data, and in one column there are Names of companies, however these names are not all exactly the same, some of the names are duplicates but have one minor difference where no conditional formula for duplicates has managed to pick up on the differences. So for example, a duplicate that i would have to mark a difference between for removal would be "JP Morgan" and "J.P. Morgan" and thus the 2 periods in the latter is something that the sheet formula i plugged in doesn't highlight the difference between the two. So far i've been manually looking to catch the differences but there has to be a better and more efficient way. Is there any formula i can plug in that can pick up on the subtle differences and highlight what are possible duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is "Fuzzy Search" capability.  There is an add-in for Excel:

[Fuzzy Lookup Add-In for Excel](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011).

And there are fuzzy search add-ins for Google Sheets also:

[How to work with Find Fuzzy Matches add-on for Google Sheets](https://www.ablebits.com/google-sheets-add-ons/find-similar/howto.php)

[Find Fuzzy Matches](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/find-fuzzy-matches/cadkkijbhldndjaflcbapfllpolajpcp?hl=en)

Answer (score -2):

you can use Fuzzy lookup for google sheets addon.To download here is the link
https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/fuzzy_lookup_for_sheets/400020812065