# Is there a Fuzzy Lookup Plugin Or Something Similar for Excel for Mac?

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, plugins, vlookup

I work with marketing/sales data and constantly need to fuzzy match lists of account names to our database. Because companies often have variations of the same name (ie. Coca Cola Inc. vs. Coca Cola Incorporated) I cannot do an exact match using VLOOKUP. Instead I typically use the Fuzzy lookup plug-in for Excel to do an approximate match and sort through results to quickly select valid matches. Unfortunately I am using a Mac now instead of a PC and I am not able to download this Excel Plug-in.

Is there a Fuzzy Lookup Plugin for Excel on Mac or a similar tool that is compatible with Macs?

The other option I am considering is getting windows and using bootcamp to partition my computer so I can download Excel for PC and get the plugin but this is a huge hassle and I'll have to pay for Windows. Any other workarounds?

Comment: See the answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1233943/how-can-i-track-highlight-duplicates-on-google-sheets/1233951#1233951).

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for a while for a **Mac** works but could not find anything and have resorted to using a virtual machine running Windows (AWS instance - worth a look). fuzzyjoin package in R is also very good for this!